# Stuck in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT id, case_id
FROM `case_note`
WHERE `type` = 'follow-up-open'
AND `follow_up_status` =1
GROUP BY `case_id`
ORDER BY case_id DESC
```

recently i have used this query to get the unique results, i have got the `id, case_id` that is :

```
id    case_id
141   23
84    16
47    14
36    1
```

this query shows the followups created by agents, this will display all the follow up that has `follow_up_status=1` means followup created, and `follow_up_status=2` means followup closed.

Now the problem is let's talk about `case_id=23`. This case is closed with the `id=145`. Now i don't want to display this Case. But if in Future if a Case will open on this `case_id` then again it will display in Followups List.

let's say a new Case open with `id=149` then i want to again display this case. I can't figure out that how to handle this approach, Please help me to guide some clue.

**UPDATE:** Here is the sample data: 
[image: Sample Data]

**UPDATE:** My Issue is resolve but don't know how do i close this question, i just updated here. I tried to resolve my problem in single query, but i have divided my query into two queries and resolved the problem.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? as soon as there will be a new row in your table with case_id=23 and follow-up-status=1, it will be selected by your query

Comment: Provide sample data and expected result for more clearance...

Comment: @Roy the problem with when the follow-up-status=2, as seen `id=145 case_id=25` has already closed this case, i want if the case id closed with `follow-up-status=2` then don't want to show that case, this is my half query, i need guidance to solve this problem.

Comment: @jogesh_p then you need a subquery. It should be easy to write one: `where 2!=(select ...`

Comment: @hims056 i have updated my question with sample data.

Comment: @JanDvorak can u provide any example if possible, i am familiar with subquery but don't know where i have set that subquery :(

Answer (score 0):

From the hip, but I'll be trying to recreate your SQL table to test it myself...

```
SELECT `id`, `case_id`
FROM `case_note`
WHERE `type` = 'follow-up-open'
GROUP BY `case_id`
HAVING SUM( `follow_up_status` ) = 1
ORDER BY `case_id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same situation what I did was,

You can Keep a log table. Let's assume that your table name is case. Create a table called case_log.

When you want to open up the case again, move the existing record to the log table. and update the existing row with the new data.

Eventually you will have your old records in the log table and new records current table where you can track the progress of any case you want. With the use of case_id you can track what has happened with the case.

If you don't want to track past data just right way update the table. I hope you need all your data since you are following this procedure.

if you have any issue let me know.

Answer (score 0):

When case_id 23 is reopened by id 149, you can use UPDATE to change it's follow-up-status:

```
UPDATE case_note
SET id=149, follow_up_status=2
WHERE case_id=23
```

Or, if you want to keep the info about case_id 23 beeing once closed by id 141 AND record the new case status, simply add a new row:

```
id    case_id    follow_up_status
149   23         1
```

This row will be selected by your current query.